# Split value with comma separate in mvc View

Tags: c#, html, razor

I want to show value in separate column which is join with comma in a column

Coming Value Is

```
S/N         Data
 1        Nitesh,ramesh,rahul
 2        Rahul,ram.Shyam
 3        Nilu,Heri,Haru
```

I want data in this Format  This Is Tolist

```
S/N       Data1          Data2      Data3     
 1        Nitesh        ramesh      rahul
 2        Rahul         ram         Shyam
 3        Nilu          Heri        Haru
```

Here Data1, Data2, Data3 are different column names

Code Is

```
  @foreach (var v in ViewBag.v)
  {

    <tr>
           <td>@i</td>
            <td>@v.Data</td>  //Data:- Nitesh,ramesh,rahul
            </tr>
             i = i + 1;
         }
```

Comment: Whats the deal with jquery,html,mvc and php here?

Comment: Use string.Split then.

Answer (score 0):

Probably better to give this in your ViewBag as list, if this is not possible you could use split:

```
 @foreach (var v in ViewBag.v)
{
<tr>
    <td>@i</td>

    @(var d in ((String)v.Data).Split(','))
    {
    <td>@d</td>
    }

</tr>
i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: @foreach(var d in ((String)v.Data).Split(','))